# Redirect http to https and www to non-www?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I searched in Google for this and 
checked over 50 posts but none seems to work. Lets assume that I have a domain example.com. What I want to do is redirect

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com
```

Can anybody please help me??
Any help would be appriciated.

**Note: I'm using cloudflare and I don't have access to conf file. I have access to .htaccess files.**

**EDIT1**:My htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It doesnot redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in Cloudfare:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```